# Traveling after expired student visa and expired NIE residency card

Tags: visas, eu

My daughter is in Barcelona Spain finishing her Master’s but her student visa expired in November 2021 and her residency card expired March 4 2022.

She is due to return to US end of April 2022. We are going to visit her in early April and planned to go from Barcelona to Italy with her for a few days.

Is she permitted to leave Spain, enter Italy and return to Spain just using her US passport or will she be prevented from traveling out and returning to Spain for the remainder of her stay because the visa and NIE expired?

Comment: Did your daughter apply to extend her visa/residency card?

Comment: No unfortunately she did not

Comment: As a _practical matter_, you should not experience immigration checks between Spain and Italy as both are members of the Schengen area, and if anybody does check, they will probably do no more than glance at a US passport. But this does not answer the question of what exactly is allowed according to Spanish law when a residence permit expires and is not renewed on time in the case where you encounter some particularly zealous official.

Comment: Thank you if you have any other suggestions as to who or what to check please let me know. I appreciate this.